# EJS Blocks and template inehritance

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am looking to avoid duplication of html code on each page.
Does EJS have Django like

```
blocks and extends
```

Comment: I found an alternative http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/  Disclaimer: I am not associated with swig in any way. For sure I'd like to learn if there is a way to do django like blocks in ejs.